How to transform complex property values (additionalFilters) from yaml into domain objects (FilterCondition)?
I am using conversion service and custom converter to transform additionalFilter list element in FilterCondition object.
Now, When I'm starting my application, it should go to this converter at debug time, it is not reaching there and also not throwing any error? No idea why.
when the debugger is coming here to the generic conversion service
converters shows list of 1 having MatchConverter but has no fields to display.
Am I missing something?
class MatchStrategy {
    private MatchStrategyType matchStrategyType;
    private List<MatchCondition> matchConditions;
}

class MatchCondition {
    private String condition;
    private List<String> additionalFilters;
    private List<FilterCondition> filterConditions;
}

class FilterCondition {
    private FilterName name; // FilterName is enum
    private FilterOp op; //FilterOp is enum
    private String value;
}


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "config.yml", factory=yamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class AppConfig {

@Bean(prefix = "strategies")
List<MatchStrategy> strategies(){
return new ArrayList();
}

@Bean
public GenericConversionService conversionService(List<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    GenericConversionService conversionService = new GenericConversionService();
    converters.forEach(conversionService::addConverter);
    return conversionService;
}
}

@Component
public class MatchConverter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, MatchCondition> {

    @Override
    public MatchCondition convert(Map<String, Object> source) {

        List<String> additionalFilters = ((List<String>) source.get("additionalFilters")).stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<FilterCondition> conditions = parseFilters(additionalFilters); //additionalFilters -- steam , for each split and save values in FilterCondition

        return MatchCondition.builder()
                .condition(condition)
                .additionalFilters(additionalFilters)
                .build();
    }

}

*config.yml:
strategies:

matchStrategyType: BEST_MATCH
matchConditions:

condition: "customerNo == 008 || agentNo == 009"
additionalFilters:

"cd == 0"




matchStrategyType: BEST_FIND
matchConditions:

condition: XYZ
additionalFilters:

"ABC != 'O'"
"SUV == 'P'"*





**the aim is basically that the application should throw and error at startup time if value in the yml file is other than the enum set.
Ex: additionalFilters:
- "ABC != 'O'"
- "SUV == 'P'"
ABC is let's say is present in FilterName and != is present in FilterOp
However, if SUV is not present in FilterName, then it should throw the error/exception at application startup. I am open to design change as well. **

Do you have any source code and custom unit test setup for this? The question seems to be confusing and requires examples.

Hi, I don't have unit test cases and the source code can't be shared. I have shared across the part which is required to get the requirement done.
Kindly share your doubts to get the clear understanding.

Did you verify that the List<String> additionalFilter inside MatchConverter contains the intended list while debugging the application?

The debugger is not getting inside the match converter class
